# Why do my IPTables rules not work for port 445 (SMB)?

Tags: iptables, router, nat, port, tcp

Consider the following rules running on my router on `192.168.1.1` (yes, they're unconventional):

```
iptables -t filter -I       INPUT 1 -p tcp --source 192.168.0.0/16 --destination-port "$PORT" --jump ACCEPT
iptables -t nat    -I       INPUT 1 -p tcp --source 192.168.0.0/16 --destination-port "$PORT" --jump SNAT --to-source      192.168.2.1
iptables -t nat    -I  PREROUTING 1 -p tcp --source 192.168.0.0/16 --destination-port "$PORT" --jump DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.1
```

When `$PORT` is *not* `445` (say, when it's `444`), these rules work fine.
When `$PORT` is `445` (SMB), though, these rules do not work.

Note that I do **not** have Samba (or anything else caring about port 445) running on the router, though you should be able to infer this from the fact that `socat` has no listening conflict below.
(And no, I do not have any other `iptables` rules regarding port `445`.)

For example, I observe the following on my router

```
$ socat -d -d tcp-listen:444 -     # this is on the router
socat[29117] N listening on AF=2 0.0.0.0:444
socat[29117] N accepting connection from AF=2 192.168.2.1:42339 on AF=2 192.168.1.1:444
socat[29117] N reading from and writing to stdio
socat[29117] N starting data transfer loop with FDs [6,6] and [0,1]
socat[29117] N socket 1 (fd 6) is at EOF
socat[29117] N exiting with status 0
```

when I run the following on a local machine:

```
netcat -w 1 -t -n -z "$(dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com)" 444 <<<"" && echo Success || echo Failed
```

However, if I do *exactly the same things above* with port `445` rather than `444`, `socat` stays forever `listening on AF=2 0.0.0.0:445` and `netcat` prints `Failed` after a short pause.

Therefore, **I suspect something in the router's kernel** is filtering out public traffic to port `445`, probably for security reasons (yes, I'm well aware of the security issues).
However, that is obviously just a guess, and I have no idea how to check/disable what is going on.

#### How might this be happening and how can I verify this?

---

Here's some more info that might help. Let's say I enable logging

```
iptables -v -t nat -I       INPUT -d "$MACHINE_IP" -j LOG
iptables -v -t nat -I      OUTPUT -d "$MACHINE_IP" -j LOG
iptables -v -t nat -I  PREROUTING -d "$MACHINE_IP" -j LOG
iptables -v -t nat -I POSTROUTING -d "$MACHINE_IP" -j LOG
iptables -v -t nat -I       INPUT -s "$MACHINE_IP" -j LOG
iptables -v -t nat -I      OUTPUT -s "$MACHINE_IP" -j LOG
iptables -v -t nat -I  PREROUTING -s "$MACHINE_IP" -j LOG
iptables -v -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s "$MACHINE_IP" -j LOG
```

where `$MACHINE_IP` is just the IP of my local machine. Now if I run

```
netcat -w 1 -t -n -z "$PUBLIC_IP" 444 <<<"Test" && echo Success || echo Failed
```

I get back the following (where I've formatted & redacted as appropriate):

```
kernel:        IN=br0 OUT= MAC="$MAC" SRC="$MACHINE_IP" DST="$PUBLIC_IP" LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=51334 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=42366 DPT=444                     WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
kernel: ACCEPT IN=br0 OUT= MAC="$MAC" SRC="$MACHINE_IP" DST=192.168.1.1  LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=51334 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=42366 DPT=444 SEQ=496897934 ACK=0 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (<redacted>)
kernel:        IN=br0 OUT= MAC="$MAC" SRC="$MACHINE_IP" DST=192.168.1.1  LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=51334 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=42366 DPT=444                     WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
kernel: ACCEPT IN=br0 OUT= MAC="$MAC" SRC="$MACHINE_IP" DST=192.168.1.1  LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=51335 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=42366 DPT=444 SEQ=496897934 ACK=0 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (<redacted>)
```

But, if I run

```
netcat -w 1 -t -n -z "$PUBLIC_IP" 445 <<<"Test" && echo Success || echo Failed
```

then I only get back:

```
kernel:        IN=br0 OUT= MAC="$MAC" SRC="$MACHINE_IP" DST="$PUBLIC_IP" LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=40192 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=39617 DPT=445                     WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
kernel:        IN=br0 OUT= MAC="$MAC" SRC="$MACHINE_IP" DST="$PUBLIC_IP" LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=40193 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=39617 DPT=445                     WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

It's weird that `$PUBLIC_IP` doesn't get translated at all in the second one. Why would that happen? etc.

Comment: I would start by telling us what the router is. We can't tell you how to verify it if we don't know what you're looking at.  If it's a home router, you're probably on the wrong site.

Comment: pcaps and complete iptables rulesets would probably be helpful.  Also the netfilter processing traces (`iptables [...] -j TRACE`).

Comment: @womble: To be honest I'm hesitant to post detailed router information... I'd rather not make the precise network setup public, as you might imagine. Can I ask what you think might cause a different behavior for different port numbers when none of them is listed in the rulesets? i.e. what would you be looking for besides the actual port numbers being of significance (which I can already see don't exist)?

Comment: To put it bluntly, we don't trust that you're not missing something obvious.  You *say* they're not in there, but plenty of questions posted here turn out to be down to the OP not noticing something that a fresh set of eyes notices immediately.  "When you see hoofprints, think horses, not zebras" -- it's far more likely that it's something simple and obvious, rather than strange in-kernel settings that nobody else has ever heard of.  You don't have to post anything you don't want to, but the chances are you won't get an answer otherwise.

Comment: @womble: Yeah, I've missed tons of obvious things before myself... I wouldn't trust me either. Sadly despite that I'm not sure I'd like to post the information requested here, as much as I would normally want to. :\ If it becomes enough of a pain to be worth it I might change my mind later though. Thanks for the comments in either case!

Comment: Are you sure your ISP isn't blocking this?  Lots of malware targets SMB, so small business and consumer connections (cable/dsl) are going to be blocking incoming SMB.  Nothing you do on your router/firewall will help.  I would verify by temporarily replacing your border device with something that can run tcpdump/wireshark, then making an incoming SMB connection from something outside to see if anything gets to the machine running tcpdump.

Comment: @Zoredache: Ah sorry I thought I had mentioned this, but apparently I forgot. But `tcpdump` indeed shows the `445` traffic; it's not entirely getting filtered out. (And the packets don't have any reason to leave the local network either, given that this is the router's own IP...)

Comment: @womble: I added some more info that might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out myself. It was a kernel module. `echo 0 > /proc/net/lfpctrl` fixes the issue.

Comment: That appears to be associated with a [proprietary kernel module](https://github.com/RMerl/asuswrt-merlin/blob/master/release/src-rt/linux/linux-2.6/net/ipv4/netfilter/lfp.c) that appears to be for Asus routers, whose sole purpose is to futz with port 445 traffic.  It's good that you figured this out on your own, but mentioning you were running an Asus might have triggered a memory in someone and they could have pointed you in the right direction quicker...

Comment: @womble: Yeah, oh well. Hope this at least helps someone else.